# JBoss 5 OracleDataSource encryption and integrity configuration and Spring 2.5

Tags: spring, encryption, jboss, datasource

How to configure Oracle Net native encryption in JBoss server? How to configure jboss 5 datasource for oracle thin client, database connection encryption and integrity for secured connection? I got application managed datasource examples, but i need jboss managed datasource with encrypted connection and integrity by configuring datasource ds.xml in jboss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ds.xml, you can pass in driver's properties using "connection-property".

If you want the Oracle JDBC thin driver to require encryption then set this property "oracle.net.encryption_client" to "REQUIRED".

```
<connection-property name="oracle.net.encryption_client" type="java.lang.String">REQUIRED</config-property>
```

Similarly to enforce checksumming, you need to set this property "oracle.net.crypto_checksum_client" to "REQUIRED":

```
<connection-property name="oracle.net.crypto_checksum_client" type="java.lang.String">REQUIRED</config-property>
```

Be sure that the Database server is at least "accepting" encryption and checksumming otherwise you'll get an exception while trying to connect. That's because you're making encryption and checksumming a requirement by setting the value of these properties to "REQUIRED". Note that by default the driver will "accept" encryption and checksumming if the server is requesting them.

You can also look into using SSL for the JDBC thin driver connections.